# How can I parse a querystring using liquid template in Azure API-Management set-body?

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-api-management, dotliquid

I hope someone sees this and know exactly what to do.  I feel like I tried everything :(.  To give a little background, I'm trying to create a generic rest endpoint to proxy a SOAP reporting service backend and pass the query string keyValues as parameters.

I started down the path using context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query which is: `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string[]>` and loop through the keys and values.  This is my preferred method but I was recieving the error:

> Liquid syntax error: Object '[p_customer_name, System.String[]]' is
>   invalid because it is neither a built-in type nor implements
>   ILiquidizable

Code to produce above:

```
<v2:listOfParamNameValues>
    {% for parameter in context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query %}
    <v2:item><v2:name>{{parameter.Key}}</v2:name><v2:values>
            {% for value in parameter.Value %}
            <v2:item>{{value}}</v2:item>
            {% endfor %}
        </v2:values></v2:item>
    {% endfor %}
</v2:listOfParamNameValues>
```

I gave up on that and began to parse the QueryString myself just so I could move on but using `Split: &amp;` or `Split: '&amp;'` just seem to ignore the & and `Split: '&'` causes an error:

> One or more fields contain incorrect values: An error occurred while
>   parsing EntityName. Line 15, position 123.

```
<v2:listOfParamNameValues>{% assign parts = context.Request.OriginalUrl.QueryString | Remove-First: '?' | Split:'&amp;' -%}
    {%- for part in parts -%}
        {%- assign keyValues = part | Split:'=' -%}
        {%- for keyValue in keyValues -%}
            {{-keyValue[0]}}:{{keyValue[1]-}}
        {%- endfor -%}
     {%- endfor %}</v2:listOfParamNameValues>
```

I'm open to any ideas, let me know if there is anything else I can add that may help.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the content of **context.Request.OriginalUrl.QueryString** ?

Comment: ?p1=test1&p2=test2

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation last week. Let me investigate this and get you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a limitation when using the Ampersand to do a split within the API Management policies inside of the set-body with liquid template.

To get around that I used an additional policy, like this:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-variable name="query_string_params" value="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.QueryString.Substring(1).Replace("&","|"))" />
    <set-body template="liquid">
        {% assign parameters = context.Variables["query_string_params"] | Split: "|" %}
        <parameters>
        {% for p in parameters %}
            <parameter>
                {% assign parts = p | Split: "=" %}
                <name>{{parts.first}}</name>
                <value>{{parts.last}}</value>
            </parameter>
        {% endfor %}
        </parameters>
    </set-body>
</inbound>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Liquid filters are case sensitive an it seems that dotliquid [uses this convention by default](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-for-Designers#filter-and-output-casing).

```
{% assign parts = context.Request.OriginalUrl.QueryString | remove_first: '?' | split:'&' -%}
```

Comment: We have dotliquid configured to use Pascal casing.  That was a mistake... sigh.

Comment: It is not the liquid filters that are failing so the case is correct for the API Management policy.  It is the '&' that is causing my issue.  I can split on '=' just fine.